# How to install theme bought in themeforest in wordpress.com?

Tags: wordpress

I have downloaded a paid theme from themeforest. Now, in wordpress.com to install a theme in a website we need business plan which is $200.So I want to ask that is there any way to  install the theme in wordpress website without purchasing business plan.Thank you in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 1):

You are using wordpress.**com**, you can not install it without getting business plan.
If you want to do this cheaper you should get website hosting at different provider and install wordpress.**org** on it. Then you should install you theme on it.